# how to sort an array of numbers in javascript making sure that the first count finished before adding duplicates?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this array of numbers that i am working with that currently look this;

```
count = [1,4,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,5,7];
```

How can i transform and sort it to make it look like this;

```
count = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,3,4,5];
```

Please help, any idea out there on how to approach this?

Comment: Why `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,3,4,5]` and not `[1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,4,5]` or `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,3]`?

Comment: @NijrajGelani first a single copy of all unique values, then all duplicates. Each sorted.

Comment: Hey @NijrajGelani, In what i am working on, if the sorting did not come in that order it will override the next possible index before the rightful index element arrive. So the sorting has to come in this order ```[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,3,4,5]``` for it to work.

Comment: Please don't downvote it so it can get to those that can help me ... thanks

Comment: Your current code?

Comment: @TheMaster, that's why i added how to approach it. Still thinking of a better way to tackle it. Thanks

Comment: @NijrajGelani This sorting can fly too ```[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,3]```

I only need a case where the count must first finish before adding duplicates in any order.

Comment: Not my DV (yet), but: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_ - The question doesn't show any effort on doing it on your own. Not even a simple loop.

Comment: @Andreas, You are right but it's not like i didn't make any effort on my own. I did and i will update my post once i am done. 

All i needed is just a pointer, an approach.

I am sure the words you will use to tell me to try a loop and so on won't be up to these words you use in criticizing it. Please let's be reasonable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to create unique numbers and a hash object to keep count of duplicates:

```js
const count = [1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7];
const hash = count.reduce((obj, num) => {
  obj[num] = obj[num] ? ++obj[num] : 1;
  return obj;
}, {});
const uniq = [...new Set(count)].sort();
uniq.forEach((num, _, arr) => {
  while (--hash[num]) arr.push(num);
});
console.info(uniq);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Get unique elements and sort

2) Get remaining elements and sort

3) combine (1) and (2) arrays.

```js
count = [1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7];

const spSort = arr => {
  const uniq = [...new Set([...arr])];
  const rem = [];
  const temp_set = new Set([...arr]);

  arr.forEach(x => {
    if (temp_set.has(x)) {
      temp_set.delete(x);
    } else {
      rem.push(x);
    }
  });

  return [...uniq.sort(), ...rem.sort()];
};

console.log(spSort(count));
```